# operator |= on std::vector<bool>

Tags: c++, bit-fields, boolean-operations

The following code doesn't compile

```
#include <vector>
int main()
{
  std::vector<bool> enable(10);
  enable[0] |= true;
  return 0;
}
```

giving the error

```
no match for ‘operator|=’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<bool>::reference {aka std::_Bit_reference}’ and ‘bool’)
```

In my real life code I have a bit field with values I want to `|=` with the result of a function.

There are easy way to express the same idea, but is there any good reason for such an operator not to be available ?

Comment: You can still do `enable[0] = enable[0] | ...`.

Comment: Why not use a [`bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)

Comment: @Borgleader in my real code the length is dynamic

Comment: @Borgleader: Because that doesn't directly support this operation either.

Comment: @Amxx, Perhaps Boost's [`dynamic_bitset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) then? Its reference type does have compound assignment overloads.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Or simply `enable[0] = true;`

Comment: @DavidSchwartz : look at my full question ... In my real life code I have a bit field with values I want to |= with the result of a function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main reason would be that `std::vector<bool>` is special, and its specification specifically permits an implementation to minimise memory usage.

For vectors of anything other than `bool`, the reference type can actually be a true reference (i.e. `std::vector<int>::reference` can actually be an `int &`) - usually directly referencing an element of the vector itself.   So it makes sense for the reference type to support all operations that the underlying type can.   This works because `vector<int>` effectively manages a contiguous array of `int` internally.   The same goes for all types other than `bool`.

However, to minimise memory usage, a `std::vector<bool>` may not (in fact probably will not) work internally with an actual array of `bool`.  Instead it might use some packed data structure, such as an array of `unsigned char` internally, where each `unsigned char` is a bitfield containing `8` bits.   So a `vector<bool>` of length 800 would actually manage an array of `100` unsigned char, and the memory it consumes would be `100` bytes (assuming no over-allocation).  If the `vector<bool>` actually contained an array of `800` `bool`, its memory usage would be a minimum of `800` bytes (since sizeof(bool) must be at least `1`, by definition).

To permit such memory optimisation by implementers of `vector<bool>`, the return type of `vector<bool>::operator[]` (i.e. `std::vector<bool>::reference`) cannot simply be a `bool &`. Internally, it would probably contain a reference to the underlying type (e.g. a `unsigned char`) and information to track what bit it actually affects.   This would make all op`=` operators (`+=`, `-=`, `|=`, etc) somewhat expensive operations (e.g. bit fiddling) on the underlying type.

The designers of `std::vector<bool>` would then have faced a choice between

1. specify that `std::vector<bool>::reference` support all the
   op`=` and hear continual complaints about runtime inefficiency from
   programmers who use those operators
2. Don't support those op`=` and field complaints from programmers who think such things are okay ("cleaner code", etc) even though they will be inefficient.

It appears the designers of `std::vector<bool>` opted for option 2.  A consequence is that the only assignment operators supported by `std::vector<bool>::reference` are the stock standard `operator=()` (with operands either of type `reference`, or of type `bool`) not any of the op`=`.   The advantage of this choice is that programmers get a compilation error if trying to do something which is actually a poor choice in practice.

After all, although `bool` supports all the op`=` using them doesn't achieve much anyway.   For example, `some_bool |= true` has the same net effect as `some_bool = true`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do the following?

```
enable[0] = enable[0] | true;
```

Comment: Thats what I'm doing, but still a would find an |= operator to be cleaner ... (not that I love those kind of operator, such as doing `^= true` for toggling a bool)

Comment: You could overload the operator as suggested by David Schwartz, but I think for such an elementary operation, this is good enough. Your call.

Comment: I also don't think it's worth adding a operator (particularly if it is badly written and contains branches). Yet for me the main point of an operator like `|=` is not to have to the variable, hense reducing the risks of a tipo

Comment: If you insist on introducing the new operator, David Schwartz's answer is the solution to your problem.

Comment: @MooingDuck I assumed it wasn't going to be as simple as a single bool. Perhaps he wanted to do some bitwise operations on another `std::vector<bool>`.

Comment: @erip: `enable[0]` logically represents a single true/false value.  (it's actually complex blah blah blah, but it _represents_ a single true/false value)

Comment: @MooingDuck I order to solve the `juste do enable[i] = true` argment ...here his what I basically want to fo `for (const auto& v : voronoi) enable[i] |= v.intersects(wall[i]);`

Comment: @Amxx: `for (const auto& v : voronoi) if (v.intersects(wall[i])) enable[i] = true;`

Comment: @MooingDuck `v.intersects(wall[i])` is expensive, you want to use lazy evaluation to avoid computing it when `enable[i]` is already true. That's why I do `for (const auto& v : voronoi) enable[i] = enable[i] || v.intersects(wall[i]);`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to make one yourself pretty easily. Something like:

```
std::vector<bool>::reference& operator |= (std::vector<bool>::reference& a, bool b)
{
    if (b)
       a = true;
    return a;
}
```

Alternatively, [std::bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/) is a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

Short and sweet answer: `std::vector<bool>` should be avoided. Use `vector<wchar>` instead. You actually get a container back in which the bools are packed in bits, which gives different behaviour from other vectors, slow code and no-one cares a bout memory anyway. I guess by now no-one likes this anymore, but turning back the clock would break too much code...