# error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘bool&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::vector<bool>::reference {aka std::_Bit_reference}’

Tags: c++, vector, stl, lvalue, rvalue

Why do I get the error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘bool&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::vector::reference {aka std::_Bit_reference}’?

```
vector<vector<bool>> vis;
bool& visited(int x, int y)
{
    return vis[x][y]; //error
}
```

As far as I know operator[] in vector returns reference, so it should be an lvalue, but it doesn't work. What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Forgot to look up the types you're using in the documentation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's because `std::vector< bool >` is not what it looks like.

There's a *specialization* for `std::vector` with type `bool` - it's space optimized and uses a single bit for each element.

You can try to use `uint8_t` or something like this, if you need this functionality. Or just return `bool`, not `bool&`.

The reference, returned by `operator[]` is not a standard reference, but a proxy class, which complicates the things here.

There are a lot of similar questions about this here:

- [operator |= on std::vector<bool>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882959/operator-on-stdvectorbool)
- [Why vector<bool>::reference doesn't return reference to bool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399417/why-vectorboolreference-doesnt-return-reference-to-bool)
- [Is the use of std::vector<bool> objects in C++ acceptable, or should I use an alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781985/is-the-use-of-stdvectorbool-objects-in-c-acceptable-or-should-i-use-an-al)

And others. Read more about `std::vector< bool >` specialization.

Answer (score 6):

Normally, what you've assumed is the case, for literally any `vector<T>`  except `vector<bool>`. The original C++98 standard specified that as a bit-packed vector, and so references to the individual elements are impossible.

This has since been recognized as an inconvenient mistake, but backward compatibility means that it can't be changed now.