# Odd Template behaviour when T == bool

Tags: c++, templates

I don't really know how to describe this problem but I have a template class that stores an array of value  and casts it out to various data types. Generally I'm not going to cast a boolean to a float but it has to be implemented because of the way the templates work.

This causes a weird issue where when T[] = bool[] I get an error on this code:

```
virtual bool getBool(uint i) {
 bool b;
 b = *reinterpret_cast<bool*>(&values[i]);
 return b;
}
```

Compliler error:

```
error: taking address of temporary
```

But this compiles and works fine:

```
 virtual bool getBool(uint i) {
  bool b;
  T c = values[i];
  b = *reinterpret_cast<bool*>(&c);
  return b;
 }
```

These two pieces of code work exactly the same but the first will not compile when T is bool. int, float, and std::string work as intended with both versions of this code. (gcc c++11)

Why does this happen?

Comment: Is the 'array' a std::vector? (if so, std::vector<bool> is special)

Comment: Yeah it is. What's special about it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30376032/560648 just a few hours ago!

Comment: [This is](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool). Don't say array if you mean `std::vector`.

Comment: Next time present a minimal, _complete_ testcase please. It avoids issues like this, where you leave out crucial details not realising that they're crucial.

Comment: You have a class template that stores an array of any arbitrary type `T`, and you have a member function `getBool` that'll `reinterpret_cast` whatever `T` is into a `bool`?! Seems like an awesome idea.

Comment: @Praetorian There are catches for invalid casts and special cases for bool to string being changed to "true" and "false". I just wanted learn about this weird case. If there are better ways to do stuff like this I want to learn. Being condescending/sarcastic is not constructive at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the generic implementation of `std::vector<T>`, `std::vector<bool>` is many times a specialization that is implemented such that `std::vector<boo>::operator[](size_t)` returns a `bool`, not a `bool&`.

Hence,

```
std::vector<bool> v{0, 1};
v[0]; // Returns an object
bool* ptr = &v[0]; // Not allowed since v[0] returns an object
                   // by value.
```

However,

```
bool b = v[0];
bool* ptr = &b; // OK since you are taking address of b.
```

More informaton can be found at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool.

Comment: Interesting. Are there any other weird type cases with vector?

Comment: @newObjekt, `vector<bool>` is the only one that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

`values` is a `std::vector<bool>`, which is [a special version of vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) that packs the bools into bits.

The result of `values[i]` is a special [proxy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool/reference) class (or simply a copy of the `bool`, if the vector is `const`) that acts like a reference to a bool, but is unfortunately not a real reference. The "temporary" referred to by the error message is this proxy class.

See also: [Why vector<bool>::reference doesn't return reference to bool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399417/why-vectorboolreference-doesnt-return-reference-to-bool) and [this article](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/on-vectorbool).